# External Table Format Exception for reading from excel to database in c#asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, excel, import-from-excel

The problem : 
My code for Importing data into database from excel sheet works fine for .xls, but for .xlsx it gives "External table is not in the expected format." error.

Please help me with this.

The connection strings ive used are :

```
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;  Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>

<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}; IMEX=YES'"/>
```

The code is :

```
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

        FilePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; 
        Date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

        ImportData();
    }
    void ImportData()
    {
        string conStr = "";
        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                 .ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                 .ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        try
        {
            conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "YES");
            OleDbConnection Econ = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

            Econ.Open();
            //string Query = string.Format("Select [Id],[Name],[Status] FROM [{0}]", FileName);

            //string Query = string.Format("Select [Id],[Name],[Status] FROM [XYZ$]");
            string Query1 = string.Format("Select [Id],[Name],[Status] FROM [Sheet1$]");
            OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(Query1, Econ);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(Ecom);
            oda.Fill(ds);

            string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TempDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
            con.Open();
            DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];
            //creating object of SqlBulkCopy    
            SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
            //assigning Destination table name    
            objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Trial";
            //Mapping Table column    
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Status", "Status");
            //inserting Datatable Records to DataBase    
            //con.Open();
            objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
            con.Close();
            ds.Clear();
            Econ.Close();
            Ecom.Parameters.Clear();
            objbulk.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: To ask the obvious, are you sure the column headers are exactly the same between your .xls and .xlsx files? I.e. no accidental extra spaces in the column headers etc.? The error message you are getting is common if the header name do not match the query.

Comment: Yes they are the same